# Javascript function out of scope - require js

Tags: javascript, function, scope, requirejs

I have a JS file named ui.js and a function within it does something. This file looks something like this

```
define(function (require) {
    function someName(param1, param2, param3) {
    ......
    };
}
```

In another JS file, I call all of my JS files like so:

```
define(function (require) {
  var $ = require('jquery');
  var functionName = require('ui');

  $(function() {

     function one() {
         .....
         someName(value1, value2, value3);
     }
  });
});
```

function one works without mistake, but when i call function someName within it, then i get an error someFunction is not defined. I must be out of the scope, but I don't know how to get this working. I tried to console.log outside and inside the someName function, and I get the log from outside but not the log from inside. Any ideas?

///// EDIT
I just mistyped it here, I have the closing brackets in my code

Comment: I think you're missing a `});` in your second bit of code. Probably just a copy/paste issue. You'll see it if you format the code.

Comment: `&` is not a valid variable name!

Comment: ups, sorry, that was supposed to be a $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're looking for this:

*ui.js*

```js
define(function() {
  return function(param1, param2, param3) {
    ...
  };
}
```

*someOtherModule.js*

```js
define(["jquery", "ui"], function($, ui) {
  $(function() {
    ...
    ui(v1, v2, v3);
  });
});
```

---

If *ui.js* should propose several methods:

*ui.js*

```js
define(function() {
  return {
    f1: function() {
      ...
    },
    f2: function() {
      ...
    }
  };
}
```

*someOtherModule.js*

```js
define(["jquery", "ui"], function($, ui) {
  $(function() {
    ...
    ui.f1();
    ui.f2();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Your first two blocks did the job.

Comment: @gogo_rulez Glad I could help :) But I suggest you to read the [RequestJS API](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html), quite complete and educative.